# How can Erlang os:cmd/1 run a command with Unicode characters?

Tags: unicode, operating-system, erlang, cmd

5> os:cmd("touch 编程").

> exception error: no function clause matching os:validate1([32534,31243]) (os.erl, line 330)
>        in function  os:cmd/1 (os.erl, line 165)

Comment: I just got an idea. First io:write_file/2 the unicode command in a temporary file(i.e. foo). Then os:cmd("sh foo"). Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erlang uses latin1 for its source files which means that you cannot use chinese or any other symbols which are not in the latin1 encoding directly in the code.

The easiest way to achieve what you whant is:

```
Name = [231,188,150,231,168,139,10].
os:cmd("touch " ++ Name).
```

Comment: Also note that if you run the code in the shell, and the locale is set to UTF-8, then you can enter unicode characters in strings, which may add to the confusion. But currently, you can't do it in source files. Furthermore, before you send UTF-8 encoded characters to os:cmd, you need to be sure that the shell that executes the command also will have the correct locale setting when started from Erlang.

Comment: Thank Svetlin and Richard. It seems I need to read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your shell's locale is `UTF-8`, just do this:

```
os:cmd(binary_to_list(unicode:characters_to_binary("touch 编程")))
```

But in source files, you can simply write

```
os:cmd("touch 编程").
```

And save the file in `UTF-8`, then everything will work fine.

Seems that the Erlang parser had done something special to the literal strings.